# Gitlab - access to source of another project on same instance

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, gitlab

Assume, I have project C++ project called A which uses libraries generated in project B. That two project are placed on my Gitlab instance. What I want to do, is to make Continuous Integration Pipeline for project A. That pipeline gets the source of project B, build a library and links it to project A. How to make project B accessible from project A? Many other projects, like C, D, etc. use projects' B library.

Comment: git clone maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "access project B from project A"? If the source of B is acquired and linked properly it means that project B is already properly accessible from project A, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it means project B is accessible from other projects.